# Discrete Math - "No computer science students are engineering students"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Struggling with a homework problem here and can't understand logically which one would be correct (each has different truth tables). I need to express the following statement using quantifiers, variables, and the predicates M(s), C(s), and E(s)

> "No computer science students are engineering students"

D = set of all students

C(s) = "s is a computer science major"

E(s) = "s is an engineering student"

So I'm stuck between,

$\forall s \in D, C(s) \implies \lnot E(s)$

-OR-

$\forall s \in D, \lnot C(s) \land E(s)$

Comment: You don't even use $E(s)$ in your statements - is the title correct?

Comment: The statement in English concerns computer science and engineering students. However, your logical statements concerns computer science and math students.

Comment: Sorry, I blanked and meant to use E(s) in place of M(s). Edited.

Comment: The second one means that every student is not a computer science student and is an engineering student.

Comment: Note that $\lnot(C(s)\land E(s))$ is equivalent to $C(s)\implies \lnot E(s)$, but both are different from $\lnot C(s)\land E(s)$; the latter means $(\lnot C(s))\land E(s)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

For every student, his/her being a computer science student guarantees that they are not engineering students.

**EDIT:**

Your second logical statement claims every student is an engineering major *and* not a computer science major.

Your first logical statement is correct. But, do say if you see how this is so or if you would like further explanation.

Comment: I got it! Makes sense between you and Q the Playtypus' answers. I had that originally and looked for further clarification online and was thrown off by the second statement (I couldn't prove to myself it WAS wrong). Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @zr0z You're most welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

The first example says "All computer students are not engineering students".  People who are not computer students are free to be maths students or not be maths students.

The second one says "All students are not computer students and they have to be engineering students".

Answer (score 1):

> "No computer science students are engineering students"

- $\neg \exists s {\in} D ~(C(s)\wedge E(s))$ "there is not a student who is both".
- $\forall s {\in} D ~(\neg C(s)\vee \neg E(s))$ "all students are either not comsci. or not eng. student"
- $\forall s {\in} D ~(C(s)\to \neg E(s))$ "all comsci. students are not eng. students"
- $\forall s {\in} D ~(E(s)\to \neg C(s))$ "all eng. students are not comsci. students"